# How to configure two servers with two charsets on Irssi

Tags: irc, irssi

I like to connect to some IRC servers with different charsets. For example, IRC-Hispano [still] uses ISO-8859-15, and Freenode uses UTF-8.

I want to use the right charset in every server. In the case of IRC-Hispano it was not easy to configure:

In settings > core:

```
/set recode_fallback ISO-8859-15
/set recode_out_default_charset ISO-8859-15
/set recode_transliterate ON
/set recode_autodetect_utf8 ON
/set recode ON
```

In settings > fe-common/core:

```
/set term_charset UTF-8
```

Where should I specify different settings (UTF-8) for Freenode? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in a huge search of irssi setups, so I'm gonna post it here. I'm sure it will help others, as well:

**Before of the settings, define `conversions`:**

```
conversions = {
    "Hispano" = "ISO-8859-15";
    "Freenode" = "UTF-8";
};
```

Then we can the defaults in settings > core:

```
recode_out_default_charset = "UTF-8";
recode_fallback = "UTF-8";
recode_autodetect_utf8 = "yes";
recode_transliterate = "yes";
recode = "yes";
```

Finally, in settings > fe-common/core:

```
/set term_charset UTF-8
```

This is the default charset of the terminal. I'm using UTF-8 in my terminal (Konsole).

There is no documentation about it in the official irssi web page. I could find a very good explanation on this [site](http://www.iovene.com/posts/2007/03/the-ultimate-guide-for-utf-8-in-irssi-and-gnuscreen/). As the author explains, we can use commands to define a different charset for every server, channel... For example:

```
/recode add freenode/gee ISO-8859-1
```

It will define the charset ISO-8859-1 on channel #gee on Freenode.